# process command git finished with non-zero exit value 128

Tags: android, git

I cloned a git project and tried to import it to my android studio and got this error. I can't seem to find the solution to this anywhere. Ps, I have configured my git account properly.

The error appears in line number 8.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
def getVersionName = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if git is not configured properly in android studio. Refer this link for step by step instruction. http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/